# Not able to use shorthand flag in "hub" (extension for GitHub command line utility)

Tags: git, github, github-api

Now I want to export all Github project issues using hub command as instructed in below link.
https://hub.github.com/hub-issue.1.html

I have used below command to see all issues.
`hub issue -s "closed"` but I am getting below error.

```
unknown shorthand flag: 's' in -s
usage: git issue

List summary of the open issues for the project that the "origin" remote points to.
```

I have tried with `hub issue --state "open"` but got same error result.

I have tried to find solution for such issue but not able to find any solution on google so friends please let me know if any one have solution for such problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `type -a hub` ? `hub --help` ? `hub --version` ?

Comment: not able to understand what you want to say here.

Comment: What happens with simply `hub issue -s` ? @phd is asking if you're sure `-s` is supported in the version you're using.

Comment: it gives me error `unknown shorthand flag: 's' in -s`  hub version is version 2.2.9. `hub --help` working.